What is Spark default pattern of the to_date function
I inherited a spark project at my work which convert string column to date one using the to_date function, sometimes with explicit date pattern (i.e. to_date(dateCol, "yyyy-MM-dd")) and sometimes not (i.e. to_date(dateCol)).
In order to understand better the code and maintain it through evolutions, I am wondering:

What pattern are recognized by the to_date method without explicit pattern argument?


Note: I found a doc (for pyspark :\ ) that states
By default, it follows casting rules to pyspark.sql.types.DateType if the format is omitted. 
Equivalent to col.cast("date").

But I couldn't find what are those rules.

For the close votes, could you please tell me what is not clear? I think the question is as specific as it is possible. Also, I asked myself this several times without finding an answer before posting on SO.

After some search I found this migration doc that states
Since Spark 3.3, when the date or timestamp pattern is not specified, Spark 
converts an input string to a date/timestamp using the CAST expression approach. 
The changes affect CSV/JSON datasources and parsing of partition values. 
In Spark 3.2 or earlier, when the date or timestamp pattern is not set, Spark uses 
the default patterns: yyyy-MM-dd for dates and yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss for timestamps. 
After the changes, Spark still recognizes the pattern together with

Date patterns:
  [+-]yyyy*
  [+-]yyyy*-[m]m
  [+-]yyyy*-[m]m-[d]d
  [+-]yyyy*-[m]m-[d]d
  [+-]yyyy*-[m]m-[d]d *
  [+-]yyyy*-[m]m-[d]dT*

So, if I understood correctly:

up to Spark 3.2, to_date without pattern and string-to-date casting recognize only the yyyy-MM-dd pattern.
Since 3.3, it recognizes all the patterns above.

